# Add rows from another df based on keys pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

**EDITED***
I have a large df with many rows that share the same value in *some* of the columns.
I want to do the following:

1. new df = identify the rows in df that have a value in a certain column (not empty).

'''

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2,2,2, 3, 4],
                   "b":['A','B','B', 'B','C','D'],
                   "c":[NaN, 2,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]})
```

'''

```
df1=df[~df['c'].isnull()]
```

'''

2. add to 'new_df' the rows from df that share 2 keys.

I tried to use merge:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1,df,on=['a','b'], how='left')
```

But the result was that It added the same row a few times and not the unique rows

```
    a   b   c_x c_y
0   2   B   2.0 2.0
1   2   B   2.0 NaN
2   2   B   2.0 NaN
```

I want to keep only one 'c' column with all the values. Not sure what approach to use.

Hope I made it clear...
Thanks!

Comment: Could you add example data and expected output? `new_df` already consists of a subset of entire rows from `df`, so I'm not sure what a merge/join with `df` is intended to achieve. Sounds like you might instead need a boolean mask with multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeimbigler, I edited my post. hope it makes it clearer. Sorry about the formatting... : )

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand the logic here. `df1` already has all rows from `df` where `'c'` is not null. What other values of `c` could you possibly gain by then merging `df1` with `df`?

Comment: Also, in this example, `df` has three rows with identical merge key values (`a=2, b='B'`), so all three rows end up in the result of the left merge onto the one row in `df1`, because that row has `a=2, b='B'`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeimbigler. So to clarify, my real table has many repeating rows. only *some* of those rows have a value in the 'c' column. I would like to create a new df that has all the rows of samples that are not empty in 'c'.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeimbigler. My real table has many repeating rows (extended example below). only *some* of those rows have a value in the 'c' column. I would like to create a new df that has all the rows of only those samples that are not empty in 'c'. in this example - I want to retrieve all the 2B because 2B has one cell in 'c' that is not empty.
But I want to end up with only one 'c' column (not c_y, c_x)

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3, 4],
                   "b":['A','A','A','B','B', 'B','C','D'],
                   "c":[NaN, NaN,NaN,2,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]})
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you would like to group by 'a' and 'b' and return only those groups where at least one row does not have a NaN in column 'c'. If that's the case. here you go

Load the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3, 4], "b":['A','A','A','B','B', 'B','C','D'], "c":[None, None,None,2,None,None,None,None]})
```

filter for any non-NaNs:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda g: any(~g['c'].isna()))
```

output:

```
    a   b   c
3   2   B   2.0
4   2   B   NaN
5   2   B   NaN
```

Comment: Hi @piterbrag. Hope you can help with a very similar challenge:
This time I have 2 dfs, which I want to combine in a similar way to the above.
Thanks!

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2], "b":['B'], "c":[2]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3, 4], "b":['A','A','A','B','B', 'B','C','D'], "c":[None, None,None,2,None,None,None,None]})

Output: 
    a   b   c
3   2   B   2.0
4   2   B   NaN
5   2   B   NaN